# How to get legend location in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to get the legend location in matplotlib. It seems like Legend.get_window_extent() should provide this, but it returns the same value regardless of where the legend is located. Here is an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def get_legend_pos(loc):

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0,1],label='Plot')
    legend=plt.legend(loc=loc)

    plt.draw()

    return legend.get_window_extent()

if __name__=='__main__':

    # Returns a bbox that goes from (0,0) to (1,1)
    print get_legend_pos('upper left')

    # Returns the same bbox, even though legend is in a different location!
    print get_legend_pos('upper right')
```

What is the correct way to get the legend location?

Comment: might be off topic but maybe you're trying to find the best legend location, but matplotlib already has this feature. using `loc=0` puts the legend at the  "best" location.

Comment: That's a good point...I know about the loc=0 (or loc='best')...what I'm trying to do is figure out where the legend was placed after using loc=0, so I can put other things around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to replace `plt.draw()` by

```
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

or, if you have a figure handle, `fig.canvas.draw()`. This is needed because the legend position is only determined when the canvas is drawn, beforehands it just sits in the same place.

Using `plt.draw()` is not sufficient, because the drawing the legend requires a valid renderer from the backend in use.

Answer (score 2):

**TL DR;** Try this:

```
def get_legend_pos(loc):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0,1],label='Plot')
    legend=plt.legend(loc=loc)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    return legend.get_window_extent()
```

**Here is why**

So I tried your code in Jupyter and I can reproduce the behavior with option

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

However for

```
%matplotlib inline
```

I am getting correct response

```
Bbox(x0=60.0, y0=230.6, x1=125.69999999999999, y1=253.2)
Bbox(x0=317.1, y0=230.6, x1=382.8, y1=253.2)
```

It looks like in the first case the legend position is not evaluated until the execution finishes. Here is an example that proves it, in the first cell I execute

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,1],label='Plot')
legend=plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.draw()
print(legend.get_window_extent())
```

Outputs `Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=1.0, y1=1.0)`.

In the next cell re-evaluate the last expression

```
print(legend.get_window_extent())
```

Outputs `Bbox(x0=88.0, y0=396.2, x1=175.725, y1=424.0)`

You probably just need to add `plt.pause()` to enforce the evaluation.

Comment: That works for me too, but I'd prefer something more direct.