# Get Seaborn legend location

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, legend-properties

I want to add comments under my legend. Here is a sample code doing what I want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=100))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=100))

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sns.distplot(df1,ax=ax,label='foo')
sns.distplot(df2,ax=ax,label='bar')
hardlocy = 0.92
xmargin=0.02
xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
xtxt=xmax-(xmax-xmin)*xmargin

leg = ax.legend()
plt.text(xtxt,hardlocy,"Comment",
         horizontalalignment='right'
        );
```

Result is:

[image]

As you can see, I rely on manual position setting, at least for y-axis. I would like to do it automatically.

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747614/how-to-get-legend-location-in-matplotlib) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711376/get-matplotlib-legend-location), I have tried to access legend characteristics through `p = leg.get_window_extent()`, but I have obtain the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'points_to_pixels'
```

(which is very similar to [this closed issue](https://github.com/scvae/scvae/issues/5))

I run MacOS Catalina version 10.15.4 and I have performed a successful `conda update --all` a few minutes ago, without any result.

How can I automatically place my comments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747614/how-to-get-legend-location-in-matplotlib

Comment: @JohanC Brilliant, cheers mate! Would you know how to convert coordinate values you obtain into something usable with `text()`?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728709/12046409) has an example with `annotate()`. `annotate()` is a version of `text()` with extra options.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohanC, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747614/how-to-get-legend-location-in-matplotlib):

One needs to draw a figure for its legend to be worked out. Therefore, a working code here could be:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=100))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=100))

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sns.distplot(df1,ax=ax,label='foo')
sns.distplot(df2,ax=ax,label='bar')
ymargin=0.05

leg = ax.legend()
fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = leg.get_window_extent()
inv = ax.transData.inverted()

(xloc,yloc)=inv.transform((bbox.x1,bbox.y0))
ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
yloc_margin=yloc-(ymax-ymin)*ymargin

ax.text(xloc,yloc_margin,"Comment",horizontalalignment='right')
```