# Is there any way to get the size of legend that will plot in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, height, width, legend

In a word, I'd like to know the width and height of a legend so that my program could modify the axes automatically.

Here is a image that illustrated my question:

[image]

As you can see, some part of the legend goes out of the axes. I think this problem could be solved if I know the height and width of the legend.

I have readed Rectangle, FancyBboxPatch and something that will helpfull, I think, on the official site.
I know that there is something about size:
For FancyBboxPatch:

```
get_frame():
  Return the Rectangle used to frame the legend. But it returns a FancyBboxPatch in fact.

get_bbox_to_anchor():
  Return the bbox that the legend will be anchored to. But I know that the function has nothing to do with my problem.
```

I'd like to know the height and width of the **grey** border that a arrow pointed. An arrow pointed the border:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get legend location in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747614/how-to-get-legend-location-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the legend is overlapping with the data, then one option is to move the legend outside the plot with [`bbox_to_anchor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) with the below as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/19261326) answer:

```py
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,1), loc="upper left")
```

Or you could try to reduce the font size with:

```py
plt.legend(fontsize=6, loc="upper right")
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But I'd like to plot the legend inside. I'd like to program for modifing the figure size to avoid overlapping automaticlly.